# how to send push notifications efficiently to selected users in an app?

Tags: websocket, push-notification

I'm trying to implement a push notification server using nodejs and websockets. The server i'm trying to implement needs to be able to send notifications that are specific to each user in the app(eg: person A commented on your post etc...). The server also can serve many apps. Therefore the number of users who use the service is very high.

The problem is how can I manage the channels. I did some research on Internet and could not find a solid solution to this. 
This [question also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993099/websockets-correct-approach-for-creating-channels-and-pushing-data) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993099/websockets-correct-approach-for-creating-channels-and-pushing-data) something similar. But does not have solid answers.

One way I thought of implementing this is to, have one channel per each user, then It may will not scale well to server many users.

Another way I thought was to organize the same messages into groups and then creates channels for the groups. Then the downside is a logged in user will need to subscribe to multiple channels and also there could be many groups that contain only one user. On the other hand the grouping process also effect the efficiency.

My question is what is/are the efficient methods to handle this problem. Can you please give me some insight into this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One way I thought of implementing this is to, have one channel per each user, then It may will not scale well to server many users.

This depends on how channels (topics, subjects) are implemented. If each channel subscription results in a new persistent connection then this won't scale too well. However, if channels are represented at a protocol level then you benefit from having one connection per client and the technology will handle the routing of messages on channels to only the appropriate clients.

> My question is what is/are the efficient methods to handle this problem. Can you please give me some insight into this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

So, if you use a solution which implemented [PubSub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) over a single connection, scaling is much less of an issue (or doesn't become an issue quite as quickly) and you can have each user subscribe to their own notifications channel. This is IMHO the best solution to this problem and something that is common practice.

Since you are looking at Node.js you could take a look at Faye - see [subscribing to channels](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser/subscribing.html). You could also look at a hosted service, such as Pusher (who I work for) - see: [Pusher channels](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_channels).

#### Web PubSub security

The next consideration is security: how do you stop any client from subscribing to a channel. The Faye docs provide a [good security overview](http://faye.jcoglan.com/security.html) including a solution to the problem.

Pusher uses a [user authentication mechanism](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users) and [private channels](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels) which also provide a solid solution to this problem.